# How to use Infinite Ajax scroll in table, new data new <tr>

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to use jQuery's plugin Infinite AJAX Scroll but it is creating `<div class="item">` and when I try to set the class to td's it's not working at all.

**Jquery Infinite Ajax scroll settings**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
    jQuery.ias({
      container : '.wrap', // main container where data goes to append
      item: '.item', // single items
      pagination: '.nav', // page navigation
      next: '.nav a', // next page selector
      loader: '<img src="css/ajax-loader.gif"/>', // loading gif
      triggerPageThreshold: 5 // show load more if scroll more than this
    });
  });
</script>
```

**My HTML/PHP Code**

```
 echo '<table id="gradient-style" summary="LMS">
            <thead>
                <th scope="col">ID<br>Create time</th>
                <th scope="col">Тема<br>Submitter</th>
                <th scope="col">Собственик<br>Последно редактиран</th>
                <th scope="col">Статус</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="wrap">';
    $sql = "SELECT date, SUBJECT, ID, RESOLVETIME, FULLDATE, STATE, REQUESTOR, QUEUEID, CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_LNAME, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS FROM 
            (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(rt.createtime, GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) as date,
                    rt.subject as SUBJECT,
                    rt.id as ID, 
                    rt.resolvetime as RESOLVETIME,
                    rt.createtime as FULLDATE,
                    rt.state as STATE, 
                    rt.requestor as REQUESTOR, 
                    rt.queueid as QUEUEID,
                    c.name as CUSTOMER_NAME,
                    c.lastname as CUSTOMER_LNAME,
                    c.address as CUSTOMER_ADDRESS 
             FROM rttickets rt
             LEFT JOIN customers c ON (rt.customerid = c.id)
             LEFT JOIN rtqueues q ON (rt.queueid = q.id)) as list ORDER BY ID DESC ";
             $start = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
             if(isset($_GET['quid'])) {
                 if($_GET['quid'] == -1) {
                     $quid = '-1';

                     $sql .= " LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";
                 } else {
                 $quid = (int)$_GET['quid'];

                 $sql .= " WHERE queueid = '$quid' LIMIT $limit";
             }
            } else {
                $quid = '-1';

                $sql .= " LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";
            }


    if( $reds > ($page * $limit)) {
        $next = ++$page;
    }
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");

    while($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
        $id = $row['ID'];
        $show_id = str_pad($id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $state = $row['STATE'];
        $requestor = $row['REQUESTOR'];
        $customer_fname = $row['CUSTOMER_NAME'];
        $customer_lname = mb_strtoupper($row['CUSTOMER_LNAME']);
        $cust_address = $row['CUSTOMER_ADDRESS'];
        $subject = $row['SUBJECT'];
        $subject_ready = mb_strimwidth($subject, 0, 25, "...");
        $date = $row['date'];
        $createtime = $row['FULLDATE'];
        $ctime = date("Y/m/d h:i:s", $createtime);
        $resolve_sql = $row['RESOLVETIME'];
        if($state == 0) {
            $state = 'Нов';
        } else if($state == 1) {
        $state = 'Отворен';
        } else if ($state == 2) {
            $state = 'Разрешен';
        } else if ($state == 3) {
            $state = 'Dead';
        }
        if($resolve_sql == 0) {
            $resolve = $ctime;
        } else {
            $resolve = date("Y/m/d h:i:s", $resolve_sql);
        }
        echo '<tr class="item" id="item-'.$id.'"><td><a href="ticketview.php?id='.$id.'">'.$show_id.'<br>'.$ctime.'</a></td><td><a href="ticketview.php?id='.$id.'">'.$subject.'<br>'.$customer_lname.' '.$customer_fname.' ('.$cust_address.')</a></td><td><a href="ticketview.php?id='.$id.'">'.$requestor.'<br>'.$resolve.'</td></a><td><a href="ticketview.php?id='.$id.'">'.$state.'</a></td></tr></div>';
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
```

I want every new row from the database to go in `<tr>` but I can't understand how to change it

Comment: You could switch your table to divs... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: isnt there any other option to make it work with tds

Comment: You are including a </div> at the end of your echo in the last while loop, try fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stand by my original comment that you should update the code to use [divs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) with the proper display, as they will play nicer with what you are trying to accomplish, and the plug-ins you are using.

I think the selector is getting confused due to some ill formed HTML echoed by PHP.

Try this at the end of your last while loop:

```
    echo '<tr class="item" id="item-'.$id.'"><td><a href="ticketview.php?id='.$id.'">'.$show_id.'<br>'.$ctime.'</a></td><td><a href="ticketview.php?id='.$id.'">'.$subject.'<br>'.$customer_lname.' '.$customer_fname.' ('.$cust_address.')</a></td><td><a href="ticketview.php?id='.$id.'">'.$requestor.'<br>'.$resolve.'</a></td><td><a href="ticketview.php?id='.$id.'">'.$state.'</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: its working but its not styling the new data its shows with black letters in the white background I recieve this `<div class="item" id="item-628">
    <h2>
      628      ???? ?? ?? ??? ???? ?????    </h2>
  </div>` and neither in my code nor in the jquery plugin there is div clas and h2

Comment: There was another markup error, my updated answer fixed it, but I doubt that was causing all of your issues. It's difficult for me to follow since I can't replicate the issue. Can you paste 2-3 <tr>'s of the returned data, including the encapsulating <tr>'s?

Comment: i fixed it myself the problem was that i was using test1.php and in the  Next Option from the paganation it was test.php.Thank you for you help i will mark your post as answer